# Not getting correct return value from Outlook

Tags: delphi, email, outlook

I use the following code to send emails using Outlook 2010 but the line

```
Result := MailItem.Sent;
```

returns an error

> The item has been moved or deleted

How can I fix this so the function gives me a useable return value?

```
function olSendMail(aFrom, aSubject, aBody, aTo, aCC, aBcc: string; aMailFiles: TStringList; aReceipt: boolean = False; aPreview: boolean = True): boolean;
var
  Outlook: OleVariant;
  MailItem: OleVariant;
  i: integer;
  MailInspector: variant;
const
  olMailItem = $00000000;
begin
  try
    try
      Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
    except
      Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
    end;
    MailItem := Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem);
    if olAccountValid(aFrom) then
      MailItem.SendUsingAccount := Outlook.Session.Accounts.Item(aFrom);
    MailItem.To := aTo;
    MailItem.Cc := aCc;
    MailItem.Bcc := aBcc;
    MailItem.Subject := aSubject;
    MailItem.Body := aBody;
    for i := 0 to aMailFiles.Count - 1 do
      MailItem.Attachments.Add(aMailFiles.Strings[i]);
    MailItem.ReadReceiptRequested := aReceipt;
    MailItem.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested := aReceipt;

    if aPreview = True then
      begin
        MailInspector := MailItem.GetInspector;
        MailInspector.Display(True);
      end
    else
      MailItem.Send;
    Result := MailItem.Sent;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      begin
        Logfile.Error('U_Mailing.Outlook.SendMailOutlook: ' + E.Message);
        Result := False;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call Sent, the only allowed operation is to release your reference to the MailItem object - it now belongs to the spooler and will be **asynchronously** sent and then moved to the Sent Items folder. Only at that moment (it will be a different message now) the Sent property will be true and all the sender related properties will be populated.

Comment: OK - so what you are saying is that this is not possible to check if a mail is sent correct using this method.  Just a bit strange in 'my world' since the MAPI way gives you an option to check for SUCCESS_SUCCESS - but it is Microsoft so anything is possible.

Comment: That is correct. On the low level, calling IMessage::SubmitMessage can return S_OK, but that simply means the message has recipients and they are all resolved. It can happen laater that the network cable is unplugged or that your SMTP password is incorrect. Since the operation is asynchronous, all you get is an NDR.